# Importing CSV to excel incorrectly (dot and comma issue)

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

I have csv (tab delimited) file which I want to import. In one column there are numbers which decimal part should be separated by comma.

If there is number 50,59459 when imported it will be shown like 5059459,00000. Although, when in csv file is number like 20.08998 it will be imported fine.

What might be problem with not reading comma separated decimals correctly?

For importing I am using macro found on this page: http://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/csv-file-import.htm

Comment: As SO is all about code please add the macro to your post.

Comment: (I'm not clicking on a random link - is the code too big to add to your post?)

Answer (score 1):

Your regional settings are US. So if you have a csv file showing ,s it will disregard them. That story about local being set to true is just for VBA to pick up the delimiter symbol from regional settings. So you need to change the decimal symbol in regional settings before you import files with European style decimal separators. (or change it in VBA after having done some test on the data)